# How do I access the frontend of Jenkins running in a Ubuntu Docker container?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, jenkins

I'm setting up Jenkins on my local machine to get it ready for a production deployer environment. I need to make sure that my setup steps mirror the production setup. Production is running Ubuntu 16.04, while my local machine is running macOS Catalina.

To make sure I can walk through setup as will be necessary on production, I'm using Docker to run the same OS as prod and installing Jenkins in that container.

I have installed Jenkins in the Docker container (which is FROM ubuntu:16.04). I'm unsure of the next steps though. How to I expose the Jenkins frontend so that I may access it in my browser?

This may not be necessary to answer the question, but here's by Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update

# Install Jenkins dependencies and Jenkins
RUN apt-get install -y wget sudo vim apt-transport-https ca-certificates apt-utils
RUN wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > \
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y jenkins

# Install Java
RUN apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install -y openjdk-8-jdk
# add the java binaries to jenkins PATH
RUN sed -i "s|PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin|PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin|g" \
    /etc/init.d/jenkins
```

After building that, I exec in and run `service jenkins start` to start Jenkins.

Newbie to Docker, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get access to jenkins web interface you need to expose it's default port (8080) while running container with jenkins master.

For example:

```
docker run -dit -p 8080:8080 your_jenkins_image
```